# Automatically update boolean property which is depend of date (MSSQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, model-view-controller, automapper

Im searching for solution to automatically update boolean column in table. This field is "WarrantyActive". I have another column with "WarrantyDate" -> durration of warranty.
I want to create  function :  if (WarrantyDate < DateTime.Now) -> change WarrantyActive to false.

```
    public bool WarrantyIsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime WarrantyDate { get; set; }
```

Should i do this in code, when im using HttpGet of table, and check this ? Or is there any better way in MSSQL which automatically check this values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isWarrantyActive` should be a calculated property or calculated column.

As a calculated property:

```
public class Product
{
    public DateTime WarrantyDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsWarrantyActive => WarrantyDate >= DateTime.Now;
}
```

As a calculated column in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE products 
(
    product_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    warranty_date datetime NOT NULL,
    is_warranty_active AS (CAST(CASE WHEN warranty_date >= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit))
)
```

Or it can be calculated in a query:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, warranty_date, 
    (CAST(CASE WHEN warranty_date >= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)) AS is_warranty_active
FROM 
    products
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check/set directly on the property like so:

```
public bool WarrantyIsActive => WarrantyDate > DateTime.Now;
```